Running selenium cron without headless?
Is there any way to run a selenium script via cron, without using the headless flag?
When i run my script with the headless flag, it works, but as soon as i remove it, the cron job doesnt work anymore, which probably makes sense
is there any way to run a cron job without using the headless flag?
Thanks

yes you can run but why do you want to run selenium without headless with cron ?? is there any specific reason. please elaborate so that we can give you specific solution because there are multiple ways where you can run it and it might not fit your usecase.

there are some functionalities not working when i have this automation running with the headless flag, but when i disable it, it works :)
thanks
